# How to make sure that worker node can not change the broadcast variable in spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

As we can use mutable object as the broadcast variable in spark, which means the state of that object can be changed by the worker nodes very easily.

Is there any approach in which we can restrict worker nodes to not to modify the mutable object?

Answer (score 0):

The object is serialized, sent to all workers, and deserialized in each one separately. If a worker mutates the object, it will only affect that one worker. So in effect, it is already immutable.

If you want to restrict it so that even the workers can't mutate within their own JVM, you should simply use an immutable object. If necessary, create an immutable wrapper or copy around the mutable object and broadcast that.